# $\omega$ incompleteness of $\lambda$ calculus

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, lambda-calculus

In Plotkin's 'The $\lambda$-Calculus is $\omega$-Incomplete' (The Journal of Symbolic Logic Vol. 39, No. 2 (Jun., 1974), pp. 313-317), an example is given of two (untyped) $\lambda$-terms $M$ and $N$ such that for each *closed* (untyped) $\lambda$-term $c$, $Mc$ and $Nc$ are $\beta \eta$-equivalent (i.e., convertible), but $M$ and $N$ are not $\beta \eta$-equivalent.

The example he gives is very messy. Are there somewhat simple examples of such $M$, $N$?

Comment: Cross-posted six days earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432880/omega-incompleteness-of-lambda-calculus.